Bash script to find certain files and add their names to another file
When I find a file whose size is 12kb I want to copy the file name to new file input.xml
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(find /root -type f -size +12k) ]
then
    grep -r -i -s "the name of file to find it" * >> input.xml
fi

When I check input.xml it is 0kb (empty)

There is no need to use a conditional statement. find has an -exec switch that can be used to send what is returned to grep or anything else. Even if you were going to do the former, there is nothing directing grep to operate on the output of find. It is only set to use grep if the find command has any output and not on anything in particular.

I'm sorry, this really isn't clear what you want to achieve here. You want to find a file under /root that's precisely 12kB? Or that's at least 12kB? And then what, copy its contents to input.xml? What should happen if there is more than one file matching the criterion?

What is "the code of the file"? also, nothing about this seems to be XML, but you still are putting it into a file which is named input.xml. That sounds like a mistake? It's overall very unclear what you really need to do, and your script seems fundamentally wrong in multiple ways, so that we can't infer what you wanted to do, I'm afraid :(

I am assuming that what you want is to get the names of all files whose size is greater than 12k, and then grep all files in the local directory for that file name, appending the output to input.xml. If so, you can just do the whole thing with find:
find /root -type f -size +12k -exec grep -i -s {} * + >> input.xml

From man find:

 -exec command ;

Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All fol‐
lowing arguments to find are taken to  be  arguments  to
the  command  until an argument consisting of ';' is encountered.  The string '{}' is replaced by  the  current
file  name  being  processed everywhere it occurs in the
arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
is alone, as in some versions of find.   [...] The  specified  command is run once for
each matched file.   The  command  is  executed  in  the
starting  directory.   There  are  unavoidable  security
problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should
use the -execdir option instead.

And -exec command {} + is a variant of the above that works on multiple files at once. All this means is that {} is replaced by the file name of whatever find has found, so your grep will look for the file name in all files and directories under your current location.

What you were trying to do, which isn't needed as I explained above, is something like this:

find /root -type f -size +12k -print0 |
 while IFS= read -r -d '' fileName; do
    grep -i -s "$fileName" * >> input.xml
 done

Note that in both cases I have removed the -r (recurse into subdirectories) option from grep since it doesn't make sense to use that with files.
